# Foreign language string via php / mysql in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem. I use php to access the mysql database to load a string into my vb.net application (for security reasons, I do not want to access the database directly - debugging / disassembling of the password to my db). That's why i use php. But when I try to load a string in another language, I get the following:

```
Dim msg_to_app_from_server As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(URL)
```

Database is using: utf8_general_ci

Database entry | vb.net output
Добрый день | Ð”Ð¾Ð±Ñ€Ñ‹Ð¹ Ð´ÐµÐ½ÑŒ
Γεια σε όλους | Î“ÎµÎ¹Î± ÏƒÎµ ÏŒÎ»Î¿Ï…Ï‚

Is there a converter to output the clean string in vb.net? Or how can I handle this? PHP-scripts output is just that string. No other information on the page...

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have found a solution:

```
Dim to_byte() As Byte = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(msg_to_user_from_server)
Dim converted_string As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(to_byte)
MsgBox(converted_string)
```

Comment: It is great that you resolved the issue your self. However, you should be aware that you can set the [WebClient.Encoding Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.encoding?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_WebClient_Encoding) so that the `DownloadString` method applies the encoding for you.